# HTML.TextAreaFor ASP.NET MVC "Templates can be used only for field access"

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

This Line of Code is causing the below error.

Code:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => XDocument.Parse(model.TramaDetalle).ToString(), 
new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @title = "Detalle" , @style = "height: 320px;resize: none;" })
```

Error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Can this be re-written or can I not do it?

Comment: `XDocument.Parse(model.TramaDetalle).ToString()` results in a `string` - which can not be used in expression binding.

Comment: @SamAxe So what could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like.

```
@var parsedTramaDetalle = XDocument.Parse(model.TramaDetalle).ToString();
```

and

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TramaDetalle, 
new { @class = "form-control",@value=parsedTramaDetalle, @readonly = "readonly", @title = "Detalle" , @style = "height: 320px;resize: none;" })
```

another way is to parse it in controller and use directly with `Htmlhelper` like:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ParsedTramaDetalle, 
new { @class = "form-control",@value=parsedTramaDetalle, @readonly = "readonly", @title = "Detalle" , @style = "height: 320px;resize: none;" })
```

Comment: This worked for me

```
@{ Model.TramaDetalle = XDocument.Parse(Model.TramaDetalle).ToString();}
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TramaDetalle, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @title = "Detalle",})
```